# Unit or Integration testing for SSH?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpseclib

I am currently using [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) to allow me to connect to SSH.

I will be using phpseclib quite a lot to connect to many servers via SSH and execute some commands.

I have created a `SecureShell` class (like a adaptor pattern) with a few methods such as `login()` and `exec()`. These method will execute the server via phpseclib object.

I am trying to work out what is a good way to test the login and execute a command a server - should I mock it `SecureShell` class or do  Integration testing which mean I need a separate real testing server (not development local server?)

Comment: phpseclib has unit tests and it uses a real testing server. The problem with mocking with SSH is...  to really fully simulate all parts of SSH you have to basically build an SSH server and that's a project unto itself.

Comment: @neubert I meant mocking `SecureShell` which use phpseclib in the `SecureShell` constructor (eg: `$this->connection['ssh2'] = new SSH2($this->credential['host'], $this->credential['port']`); I might look into real testing server, possibly using vm via vagrant. I need to find a way to recreate a vm testing server super fast when calling phpunit. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Personally, I think Vagrant would be the best approach since it already has SSH installed. Here's an example the phpseclib author did with Vagrant: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1126#issuecomment-301335862

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you would want both.

You would want unit tests with a mocked `SecureShell` so that you know that your code is asking to run the correct commands.  You would also want to have some sort of integration tests that you can verify that your connection is setup correctly and will work in production.

Tests are so that you are confident that there are no problems with your code and that everything will work correctly.  So you want whatever tests will provide you with that confidence.

Comment: To do integration tests which is easy enough. I think mock `SecureShell` going to hard as I need to simulate all parts of SSH? For example `$ssh = new SecureShell($host, $port)` and then `$ssh->exec('ps aux')`  - how would you mock this?

Comment: you can mock functions with namespaces, similar to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18254621/498699